# Django - how to query all users associated with a "listing" object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

My models look like this:

- CustomUser has a many to many relationship with a "Listing" object
- Each Listing object has an "author" field

  ```
  author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
  ```
- Essentially, a listing has both an author (CustomUser) and custom users who need confirmation.

I'm trying to get all the custom users who need confirmation for all the listings posted by the author.

I'm not sure what the correct way to query is.

```
Listing.objects.filter(author=author).needsConfirmation_set.all()
```

The models

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rating = models.FloatField(null=True)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="followers")
    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="following")
    interested = models.ManyToManyField('Listing', related_name = 'interested', default=None)
    needsConfirmation = models.ManyToManyField('Listing', related_name = 'needsConfirmation', default=None)
    confirmed = models.ManyToManyField('Listing', related_name = 'confirmed', default=None)

class Listing(models.Model): 
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="N/A")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: You should include more of your models (interpreting model definitions in prose is hard).

Comment: added models. yes i tested it, getting an attribute error. I can think of doing this using a for loop but I would rather not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's as simple as:

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(needsconfirmation__author=author)
```